# How to customize gnome-initial-setup GUI?

Tags: linux, gnome

I found out you can customize the gnome-initial-setup GUI using a `/etc/gnome-initial-setup/vendor.conf` file as described here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-initial-setup

However, I can't find any extensive documentation on all the options which can be configured. It must exist somewhere since distribution maintainers make these changes themselves.

Does anyone know where this can be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging on my own but didn't find much else on the topic.

I never found an exhaustive list of available pages which can be displayed/skipped during gnome-initial-setup, however, I was able to effectively skip pages which I found references to (livepatch, privacy, goa, etc.)

Adding and removing options to the goa section was simple enough as described on the upstream project page, but again there wasn't an exhaustive list of options available to play with.

Overall I think this tool must be aimed more at distro maintainers who apply their own patches.